# Firebase function upload to storage

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm trying to use Firebase cloud functions to upload an image onto storage.
When I run the function from a browser, I receive a '0' response, indicating that it failed.
Afterwards I check the logs and it displays the error:

> Upload bad! [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'https://i2.wp.com/lifemadesimplebakes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/How-To-Make-Fruit-Salad-680x680.jpg'] {

The image url does exist though. So I'm wondering why it's not working?
Here's my whole cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');


exports.uploadTest = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const url = 'https://i2.wp.com/lifemadesimplebakes.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/How-To-Make-Fruit-Salad-680x680.jpg';
    
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('my-bucket.appspot.com');

    bucket.upload(url, {
        destination: "myFolder/myFile.png"
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Upload good!");
        response.send('1');
        return true
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error("Upload bad!", err);
        response.send('0');
    });
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So after some more research, I got something to work.
On my frontend I'm encoding an image to base64 which I pass to my cloud function as a parameter `imgData`. Then inside the function I retrieve it, make a `Buffer` with the data, then upload it onto my bucket using `File.save`.
Now it uploads, and if I download a url for it from the console and check it on a browser the image appears as expected.

My frontend needs to use REST so I'm unable to use Firebase's sdk at all, which probably would have made this much easier.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.uploadTest = functions.https.onRequest(async (request, response) => {
    const imgData = request.body.imgData;
    
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('my-bucket.appspot.com');
    const file = bucket.file('myFolder/myFile.jpg');

    var imgBuffer = new Buffer.from(imgData, 'base64')

    await file.save(imgBuffer, {
        contentType: 'image/jpeg'
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error("Upload bad!", err);
        response.send('0');
    });

    response.send('1');
})
```

Here's some info that helped me along:
https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/aDJvYyNIJik?pli=1

Comment: how can you initialise the app (`admin.initializeApp()`) with no config json?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Storage does not support directly uploading content from some URL.  [upload()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) doesn't take a URL.  It takes a path to a local file.

As such, you will have to write code to download the contents of the URL locally, then upload that as an object to Cloud Storage.  You could also stream the contents of the download into the storage using the SDK as well.  See [createWriteStream()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#createWriteStream) for that.  I suggest studying how [node streams](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) work in order to implement this effectively.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the great info I wasn't aware of it not taking a URL. If I got the image from my frontend, am I able to pass it as a parameter to the function, which can then upload it with that data?

Comment: Sure, you could try that.

Comment: Would the idea be that I can pass the image as a base64 string to my cloud function, then use `createWriteStream` to decode the image to storage? I can upload to my bucket with `admin.storage.bucket.file.save`, but just struggling to save it as a proper image!

Comment: You could try that too.  If you have code that doesn't work the way you expect, please post that separately in a new question.